# Gaussian Process Kernels for time series : one kernel for t<0 and one for t>0, is it possible?

Tags: scikit-learn, gpytorch, numpyro

I have  small time series, (t_i, Y_i)_{i<N}   (N ~ 20 and varying from one to another). Now, I know that for some t_i <0 the behaviour is different than for t_i>0, and from one series to the other the index "i" that cuts the two processes time zone, is different.
Well, it seems that I can cook a kernel for the time zone independently, but I was wandering that is it possible to glue both kernels?

I can use scikit-learn or numpyro or pytorch if you point me an example. Thanks

Comment: What kind of boundary conditions at t_i=0 do you want? Continuity, differentiable?

Comment: Well, the slope is certainly different. 
if Y(t) is the value at time t, then Y(0-)=Y(0+) but Y'(0-) =\= Y'(0+)

Comment: Add: one more point, there is not in general a "t_i = 0" , as for instance t_i:{-250, - 133, -50, 111, 201,...}